# how to create private network same as mainnet?

Tags: cleos, nodeos, eosjs, rpc, keosd

I want to build a private network same as the mainnet of eos. Just like it's mainnet I want to have 21 producers I want voting and etc. etc. how exactly I can do that can anyone list the steps for the same, please?

Answer (score 6):

There is [an article](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/docs/bios-boot-sequence) in the documentation detailing how you can setup and run a network with multiple producers, voting, and resource consumption.

Excerpt:

> In this tutorial, we will start a number of `nodeos` nodes, point them to each other, and eventually vote on a set of producers. All of the `nodeos` nodes will run on the same server. In the following sections, we take various steps to prepare our candidate set of producers. We will use the naming convention `accountnumXY`, with `XY` chosen from the digits 1-5

Further, BlockOne published a [Python script](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/blob/364fcc75edb30c80a1f0dae39b1d26f5d6c93a4d/tutorials/bios-boot-tutorial/bios-boot-tutorial.py) that performs the booting process for you.

Comment: Thank you but I can only make an account a block producer what if i want to have voting and make producers on my own

Comment: @yashvadhvani you can vote once you deployed all the necessary contracts including `eosio.system` via the `cleos system voteproducer prods` subcommand, but i'm not sure what you mean to "make producers on my own" any account can be made a BP via the `cleos  system regproducer` subcommand.